Odoo POS- Variants gets duplicated in POS screen when adding to order?
When I add a certain attribute with variants to more then 1 product, all the variants gets duplicated when adding them to an order. (We have the attribute set at never create variants, so the product screen is not filled with all variants)
We have 3 pizza sizes. If I assign the attribute "size" to 1 pizza, it's no problem. But If I assign "size" to more pizza's, the variants gets duplicated in the POS screen when adding a pizza to the order.
as you can see here:
https://ibb.co/SBf5fQk
Any ideas?
Thank you for the help!!
